# printing key presses to the screen instantly with python

Tags: python, keyboard, keypress

I know this question is long but what I really want to know is in bold.

I would prefer to use python on Linux.

I'm trying to make a new keyboard layout kind of like devorak but the layout is set to either layout1 or layout2 depending on if you are holding a hot key or not (the hot key should probably be ctrl?)

e.g. press d -> "z" prints to the screen using key layout1

e.g. press ctrl d -> "x" prints to the screen using key layout2

My main problem (and question that needs answering) is the way characters need to print to the screen.

if someone presses the keys (in this order) "(a)(b)(c)(d)(ctrl+d)(shift+e=E)(f)(Enter)"

now lets say the **output for these key presses should be "oijzxKb"**
I don't want output to render with new lines:

```
o
i
j
z
x
K
b
```

**I want the characters to appear instantly on the screen as each character is pressed (without waiting for them to press enter).**

```
e.g.
press o

Screenshot1 o

press i

Screenshot2 oi

press j

Screenshot3 oij

.. etc
```

I assume I will need the following:

- a way to read keypresses instantly
- a way to print key presses instantly (to the terminal or a GUI or whatever is easiest initially, if it worked on any editor that would be cool!)

I could probably do this in PyGame (but then I probably wouldn't be able to cut and paste etc) and I'm guessing there should be an easier way.

I'm using a Logitech G110 keyboard, I may eventually want to use this as an alternative to my qwerty keyboard on all my applications across all my devices.

Thanks!

### EDIT: SOLUTION:

Thanks to the first response,
using Getch from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/

```
getch = _Getch()
word=""
while True:
    c=getch.impl()
    if c=="a":
        word+="z"
    elif ord(c)==127: #backspace
        word=word[:-1]
    else:
        word+=c
    print word
```

This will suffice for now thank you. Once I'm happy with refinement I'll look at doing something lower level, operating system specific without python.

**One problem with getch however is that ctrl+a cant be distinguished between ctrl+A (e.g. if you hold ctrl and press keys, it can't tell the difference between upper and lower case)**

Comment: Python is probably the wrong tool for the task. which OS are you using?

Comment: I would prefer to use python on Ubuntu but feel free to suggest alternatives if they are simple.. perhaps I could use python for the higher level logic.

Comment: You should have a look at xmodmap, and maybe xkeymaps.

Answer (score 3):

If it's ok to depends on the X window system, you can use the [python-xlib](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/) module or the [xpyb](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/xpyb/) module to access the X window system and use a [XGrabKey](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabKey.html) call to grab the keyboard related events. Upon each `KeyPress` event you will be able to print the pressed key.

Now, if you really want to write a keymap, this is totally OS/window system dependent. If you use the X window system (Ubuntu does), you need to check the X documentation about how to write a new keymap. On Ubuntu, the current keymaps definition should be in `/usr/share/X11/xkb`. Take a look, and try to copy and edit one. You can use `setxkbmap` to change the current keymap then.

Comment: Absolutely; getting keypresses in a python program and echoing different keys to the user is completely trivial, but won't help you use any program except that one python program.

Comment: This is probably an effective long term solution. Once I'm happy with my layout I will look into implementing it this way thanks

Answer (score 1):

To modify the key mapping of your keyboard, you must use the tools provided by your OS. Most applications don't accept generated events for security reasons.

In your case, that would be `xmodmap`. Don't forget to create a backup of your current keymap using the `-pke` option because you will make a mistake - and then, your keyboard won't be working anymore.

If you also want your new keymap work on the console, have a [look at the `kbd` package](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kbd/) which changes the keyboard layout at the kernel level.

Comment: thanks, I may want to eventually use this layout on my phone too. The only problem is that because I have two layouts instead of one, I need a hotkey that switches between the two. Right now I am using shift key (so every lowercase goes to layout1, every upper case goes to layout2), however now I no longer have capitals which is a problem I would eventually like to fix. I need to double the number of combinations without loosing any original functionality.

Comment: Ubuntu supports several keyboard layouts. System Settings -> Input Devices -> Keyboard -> Layouts. Using the system tools would allow you to add a new layout, test it and then switch back to the "normal" layout.

Comment: You can also configure shortcuts there to switch between the layouts.