# Backspace with `raw_input` in Python

Tags: python, raw-input, backspace

I am using `raw_input()` like this:

```
while True:
  print "MC ID (CTRL-D = done, 0 = sets, ? = lookup):",
  try:
    mcid=raw_input()
  except:
    print
    break
  # evaluate user input
  # ...
```

Now if you type something, e.g. `abc` and hit backspace to correct something, as soon as you remove the `a`, the output from `print` is erased as well (and the cursor jumps to the beginning of the line), so that you no longer see the input prompt. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Maybe this is rather a problem with my terminal than with Python? Does somebody see the same behavior?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should never use a bare `except`.

Comment: What happens if you put your prompt string as argument to raw_input()?

Comment: The code works fine for me so yes - its a problem with your terminal :)

Comment: OK, so it seems to be somewhat related to my terminal, but it can be fixed (see the answers below) by prompting without an explicit `print`. Thanks!

Comment: You may find this of use:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151966/printing-key-presses-to-the-screen-instantly-with-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
mcid = raw_input("MC ID (CTRL-D = done, 0 = sets, ? = lookup): ")
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce it, but you can try this way:

```
mcid=raw_input("MC ID (CTRL-D = done, 0 = sets, ? = lookup):")
```